# Implement HexBox

Tags: c#, wpf

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/
I'm trying to implement the DLL portion of the download into my project so I can use the HexBox control, but it seems as if it does not show up in my ToolBox, so there's no way I can think of for putting it on forms :S

I'm just wondering how I can fix this, as I'm not sure if I'm either doing it wrong or WPF doesn't support this without a fight.­

Answer (score 1):

The HexBox control you're referring to is a WinForms control, not a WPF control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your solution with the dll referenced and then check. Also make sure that show all tools is enabled in the toolbox.

You can also use choose items and add the tool to the toolbox using its dll.

Comment: Seems neither of the solutions are working. The second one works, but they are greyed out, meaning I can't use them. I looked in the source of the DLL and rebuilt it as .NET 4, since it was at 2, but it still provided the same error.
http://gyazo.com/0fb836932193a13c12e254012a2c9728.png